# How is a conditional implemented in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, implementation

I am curious to know how a conditional statement such as an "if" is implemented in C/C++ or other programming languages.

Accordingly, how will it make difference in terms of computation cost if I write an if statement in the following two ways:

Way I:

```
if(statement1)
    return true;
if(statement2)
    return true;
if(statement3)
    return true;
```

Way II:

```
if(statement1 || statement2 || statement3)
    return true;
```

In the second way, will all the statements be first evaluated and then the OR operation applied upon their results or will the OR operation be first taken into cognizance and then as soon as any statement evaluates to true, the true value shall be returned? The latter saves the computation cost/time by not having to necessarily evaluate each and every statement in the conditional, since as soon as it gets the first true, the job is done.
But this is dependent on the operations inside the conditionals. If its an AND, it becomes a different case altogether. And things get tricker with combined operations(AND+OR+XOR..)

So how is it really done behind? Is it possible for the implementation to be case-dependent on the boolean operations inside the conditional?

Comment: Most modern compilers will generate code identical byte-to-byte for both code snippets.

Comment: You're thinking too hard.  The compiler may or may not optimize this, with or without your knowledge, so worrying about the code is almost certainly unnecessary.  Having said that, I would guess the two blocks of code appear the same after the compiler gets through with them.

Comment: The question is valid with regards to possible short circuiting; `||` is guaranteed to short circuit.  And the correct solution is simply `return statement1 || statement2 || statement3;`.  Statements like `return true` are _usually_ a sign that the programmer doesn't understand the concept of a boolean type.

Answer (score 4):

> I am curious to know how a conditional statement such as an "if" is implemented in C/C++ or other programming languages.

It depends on the assembly language of your computer. For instance, with x86 instruction listings, the instruction `CMP` will set a flag, which is read by instructions such as `J**` (`JNE`, `JA`, ...).

This is typically how a condition is "implemented".

> In the second way, will all the statements be first evaluated and then the OR operation applied upon their results or will the OR operation be first taken into cognizance and then as soon as any statement evaluates to true, the true value shall be returned?

In C, `&&` and `||` binary operators use *short-circuit evaluation*. That is, in `E1 || E2`, if `E1` is true, `E2` is not evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

> In the second way, will all the statements be first evaluated and then the OR operation applied upon their results or will the OR operation be first taken into cognizance and then as soon as any statement evaluates to true, the true value shall be returned?

Logic operators always short-circuit in C++. In the case of `||`, if the first operand is true, then the second is not evaluated. This means that both of your examples should be equivalent; the code will evaluate the expressions until one is true, then return true.

Not only is this potentially more efficient that always evaluating both; it also allows something like

```
if (!p || *p == whatever)
```

in which it would be an error to evaluate the second if the first were true.

> If its an AND, it becomes a different case altogether.

In that case, the second operand is only evaluated if the first is false.

> And things get tricker with combined operations(AND+OR+XOR..)

There is no logical XOR in C++; only `&&` and `||`. Combining them is reasonably straightforward; `&&` has a higher priority, and within each subexpression the operands are evaluated from left to right, short-circuiting as required.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation *depends* on the *compiler and optimization settings*. In some cases, Way II (the one with OR conditions) is faster due to "short-circuiting": if the operand on the left side of the || operator is true, the rest of the condition isn't checked. In Way I, on the other hand, the conditions are ecexuted sequentially - unless some kind of optimization (or a smart compiler) is used to convert it to Way II (in which case both Ways are equally fast).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the compiler.  You can see what happens by using gcc -o which will generate an object file.  Open up the object file, and you'll see hwo the compiler optimizes it.  Usually, it creates a jump table (for long conditionals), but other times it just uses conditional processor instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Smart compilers will convert Way I into Way II.

Way II checks each statement and returns true immediately upon encountering truth.

Comment: What if statementX are function calls?

Comment: Smart compilers will still convert Way I into Way II. It will still return true immediately when it encounters a truth return value.

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard:

---

5.15 Logical OR operator

```
   logical-or-expression:
     logical-and-expression
     logical-or-expression || logical-and-expression
```

1 The || operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It returns true if either of its operands is true, and false otherwise. Unlike |, || guarantees left-to-right
evaluation; moreover, the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true.

2 The result is a bool. If the second expression is evaluated, every value computation and side effect associated with the first expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the
second expression.

---

Other fact - compiler abides rules or not.